# Parralize the function by using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a a function with name `new_function(df,y)` with two arguments `df` and `y` and I am trying to apply it to a list of 100 Dataframes by using `multiprocessing` and I want to append results in a list. I went through previous posts but couldn't understand, I try this method but not able to process.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.map(new_function, df) for df in data]
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Comment: What are x, y? Are the related to the dataframe?

Comment: The signature of `new_function` is important here - what parameters does it take? What is `data`?

Comment: yes x here is  dataframe from list data and y is constant value but both x and y changes through each iteration

Comment: @dspencer new_function takes two parameters one is dataframe  df and other is constant value y. and data is list of 100 dataFrames i.e data = [ df1, df2, ....dfn] through this list I want to iterate new_function

Comment: What do you mean by `y` changes through each iteration? Is it also a list, with the same number of elements as `data`?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have

```
results = [pool.map(new_function, df) for df in data]
```

This won't work as you expect, since the second argument of `pool.map` is supposed to be the iterable for whose elements you want to execute `new_function`.

You should be able to run your `new_function` in parallel using the following approach. This code makes use of [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to generate a "partial function", i.e. with the constant `y` parameter filled using `CONSTANT`. [`pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) will execute this function for each of the `DataFrame`s contained in `data`.

```
import functools
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.map(functools.partial(new_function, y=CONSTANT), data)

    print(results)
```

Since I don't have your input data, you can see how this works using dummy inputs and a simple `new_function`:

```
def new_function(x, y):                                                         
    return x, y                                                                 

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                         
    CONSTANT = 12                                                               

    with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:                           
        results = pool.map(functools.partial(new_function, y=CONSTANT), data)   

    print(results)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 12), (2, 12), (3, 12), (4, 12)]
```

If the `y` parameter changes with `data`, i.e. you have a list of values corresponding to the different `DataFrame`s in `data`, you could use [`pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead:

```
def new_function(x, y):                                                         
    return x, y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sample data                                                    
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                         
    y_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]                                                       

    with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:                           
        results = pool.starmap(new_function, zip(data, y_list))                 

    print(results)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Comment: I tried your method for one Dataframe but it does take lot of time and can i append my output in this method to new list?

Comment: You should return the result from your `new_function`, then the results will be automatically collated into a single list once the function has been executed on all inputs.

Comment: For one `DataFrame`, the time should be roughly the same as without using `multiprocessing`. The advantage comes in that you will be able to run the function on `mp.cpu_count()` number of `DataFrame`s simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments, I want to make clear what do you mean by time for 1 DataFrame  would be same? In my case without multiprocessing it take 15 minutes for 1 dataframe. So far what I understood about parallel processing is it reduces the processing time, Do you mean it is effective and reduces time only if we apply for large number of Dataframes? As in future I need to apply function on list of 400 dataframes so don't know it could be effective ?

Comment: Parallelising like this would do nothing for the time taken for one `DataFrame`, it would simply mean that, with 4 CPUs, you could process 4 inputs in approximately the same time as 1 input running in serial.

Comment: You may also want to look at profiling your function to see if there is a part of that which could be optimised.

Comment: ok thank you for explanation. I forgot to mention in my question that each datafarme has multiple columns .does your method works if we do parallelization through entire dataframe? Stay Blessed

Comment: You could use `df.iteritems()` as the iterable in the `pool.map` call to pass each column to the function, if you wanted to parallelise over the columns, yes.